# Calculate [$\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 )$ : $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3 )$]

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory

. . . and construct a basis for $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ as a $\mathbb Q (\sqrt3)$-vectorspace.

having a hard time with this.

what I have now is $$\mathbb Q (\sqrt2, \sqrt3) = \bigl\{a + b\sqrt3 : \{a,b\}\subset\mathbb Q (\sqrt2)\bigr\}$$

as a $\mathbb Q (\sqrt3)$-vectorspace.

but I'm not sure that's even correct.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = (\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}))(\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to utilize that.

Comment: Sorry, it should read $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = (\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3}))(\sqrt{2)$, so you are getting a degree 2 extension of the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt2$ is a root of $ X^2-2\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)[X]$, this implies that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt3]\leq 2$, now show that $\sqrt2$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$ to conclude that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt3]=2$.

Suppose that $\sqrt2=a+b\sqrt3, a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, we deduce that $2=a^2+2ab\sqrt3+3b^2$, this implies that $ab\sqrt3\in Q$, thus $a=0$ or $b=0$, if $a=0$, $\sqrt2=b\sqrt3$, we deduce that $2=3b^2$, write $b={p\over q}$, $gcd(p,q)=1$, we deduce that $2q^2=3p^2$ and $3$ divides $q$, write $q=3q', 18{q'}^2=3p^2$ implies that $6{q'}^2=p^2$, we deduce that $3$ divides $p$, contradiction since we have assumed that $gcd(p,q)=1$, if $b=0$, $\sqrt2=a\in\mathbb{Q}$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Any element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ can be written as $a+b\sqrt{2} +c\sqrt{3} +d\sqrt{6}$ where $a, b ,c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$ whic is $(a+c\sqrt{3}) + (b + d\sqrt{3})\sqrt{2}$. So $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})] = 2$.

Comment: Every element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{8})$ can be written as $(a+c\sqrt{8})+(b+d\sqrt{8})\sqrt{2}$ but that doesn't mean $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{8}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{8})]=2$.